# Creating a list of tags using couchDB map reduce

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I've a list of documents (operators) and they have devices. Each of these devices has or more more tags.
I want to create a unique list of tags for each operator.

Operator1:
 Device1
   tag_1
   tag_2
 Device2
   tag_1
   tag_3

Operator2:
 Device1
   tag_4
   tag_2
 Device2
   tag_1
   tag_3

I want the output to be like

```
    Operator1 -> Tags: [tag_1,tag_2,tag_3]
    Operator2 -> Tags: [tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4]
```

How do I do this using a view (map reduce) ?
I was able to emit the documents using the below mapper.

```
    function(doc) {
        if (doc.key && doc.operator && doc.tags) {
            for (tag in doc.tags) {
              emit(doc.operator, tag.toLowerCase());
            }
         }
    }
```

This emits

```
    Key           Value
    Operator1 - > tag_1
    Operator1 - > tag_2
    Operator1 - > tag_1
    Operator1 - > tag_3
    Operator2 - > tag_1
    Operator2 - > tag_2
    Operator2 - > tag_3
    Operator2 - > tag_4
```

I couldn't figure how to group them to:

```
    Operator1 -> Tags: [tag_1,tag_2,tag_3]
    Operator2 -> Tags: [tag_1,tag_2,tag_3,tag_4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a reduce function to accomplish this:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  var tags = {};
  values.forEach(function(tag) {
    if (!tags[tag]) tags[tag] = true;
  });
  return Object.keys(tags).sort();
}
```

This will iterate the `values` (ie: "tags") and return a unique list of them.

Generally speaking, reduce functions are supposed to have very small output, like simple numbers. Depending on how large and diverse your dataset is, you may need to [configure](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/query-servers.html#query_server_config/reduce_limit) your server to allow larger reduce output.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reduce function.

```
function(keys, values) {
   return sum(values);
}
```

Then query with the parameter group=true.